# JS - Simulate form submit with "form attribute" on text input

Tags: javascript, html, forms

Consider I have the following HTML:

```
<form id="myForm" action="/echo/html/" method="post">
  <input type="text" value="10" />
  <input type="submit" value="submit" />
</form>
<input type="submit" form="myForm" value="submit" />
<input id="myInput" type="text" form="myForm" />
```

and with that HTML I have the following JS:

```
document.addEventListener('submit', function(e) {
  console.log(e, 'addEventListener');
});

document.getElementById('myInput').addEventListener('keyup', function(e) {
  console.log(e.target.form);
  e.target.form.submit();
});
```

*(Note: this code has been optimized to work in [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/q74qg8hp/) and thus uses `/echo/html/`. The docs on this are [here](http://doc.jsfiddle.net/use/echo.html))*

There are three parts to the above code:

1. The `<form>` (`id="myForm"`), which has a `text input` and a `submit input`.
2. The `submit input` outside `myForm`, but, using the attribute `form="myForm"` will submit the data inside `myForm`.
3. The `text input` which when registers a `keyup`, will fire `myForm` by using `e.target.form.submit()`. **This does not, however, fire the `submit` event attached to the document.**

My question is:

> *How do I simulate/trigger/etc. a `submit` event, which actually fires a `submit` event which is currently being listened by the `document`, using the 3rd method I describe above (on a `keyup` for a `text input`).*

*P.S. I could not get a snippet working as it was erroring in stackoverflow, so the [jsfiddle is here](https://jsfiddle.net/q74qg8hp/).*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this happens because you're triggering the event on the `form`, without it bubbling to `document`. I'm sadly unable to find out any links to the documentation about it (as, on why it happens). If anybody is able to provide such link, I'll be interested to read about it as well.

To get around this, I've created a `submit` `Event` which actually bubbles, that is captured by `document` as well:

```
document.addEventListener('submit', function(e) {
    console.log(e, 'documentEventListener');
});

document.getElementById('myForm').addEventListener('submit', function(e){
    console.log(e, 'myFormEventListener');
})

document.getElementById('myInput').addEventListener('keyup', function(e) {
    var event = new Event("submit", { bubbles: true });
    this.form.dispatchEvent(event);
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/c1vnjjxr/3/

Comment: interesting! well this works and does what I need it to do. Weird on `.submit()` (maybe) no properly bubbling to `document`.

Comment: I think that the explanation here is that programatically triggered events do not bubble (unlike mouse events), but I failed to find reference for that.

Comment: Makes sense. It would be cool if `.submit()` took a `bubble` param, almost like `new Event`. I'm guessing something like: `this.form.submit({ bubbles: true });` but your way works (just realized you could even one line it like this: `this.form.dispatchEvent(new Event("submit", { bubbles: true }));`

Answer (score 0):

The problem is the "myInput" input field is outside the form tag already. To submit the form using the outside input is to get the form and use the .submit() method.

```
document.addEventListener('submit', function(e) {
  console.log(e, 'addEventListener');
});

document.getElementById('myInput').addEventListener('keyup', function(e) {
  // console.log(e.target.form); <-- what is this for??
  document.getElementById("myForm").submit();
});
```

Comment: HTML5 allows you for placing input elements outside the form they belong to - that's what `form` attribute is for. You can access the form by accessing `.form` property - so, either `e.target.form` (`e.target` is target of keyup event, in this case `#myInput`)  or `this.form` is fine

Answer (score 0):

Why would you need this?

```
document.addEventListener('submit', function(e) {
  console.log(e, 'addEventListener');
});
```

Just put the inputs inside the form, so they'll be able to submit it.

Comment: my idea was to use the `form` attribute on the `text input` (`<input form="myForm"`) so that I can place the `text input` elsewhere on the page but still have it connected to `myForm`